# Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wt

Tags: mysql, eclipse, jsp, jdbc

I know I am not supposed to use this code on JSP, but I just wanna check the connectivity to the database. So I am using this to check with a JSP page. But when I checked it, it threw me an error like this:

```
Error: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wt
```

Source code of `database.jsp`:

```
    <section>
      <h3><code>Users</code> Table</h3>
<%
    Connection con = null;
    Statement st = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/wt";
    String user = "root";
    String password = "";

    try {
        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        st = con.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT VERSION()");

        if (rs.next()) {
            out.println(rs.getString(1));
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
%>
    </section>
```

I have also included `mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar` to the list of libraries. I am using the following stack:

- MySQL 5.6.17
- Eclipse Luna (J2EE Perspective)
- JBoss 6.1 Distribution Server

Please guide me where I am going wrong. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Load the class:

```
Class.forName(mysqlDriverClass).newInstance();
```

Before you invoke any jdbc methods?

UPDATE

---

Include the SQL JSTL class using `<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql"%>` and set your datasource `<sql:setDataSource var="snapshot" driver="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/TEST" user="root"  password="pass123"/>` to whatever you need. Be sure to include the [jstl jar](https://jstl.java.net/download.html).

Comment: I got this error: `org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /Database.jsp at line 33`. What to do?

Comment: ps: I am using it in a `.jsp` file.